# Does LVP flooring on stairs need nailing?

Tags: flooring, stairs

I got Shaw Bowman Plus LVP installed and there are like 400 nail holes over 18 steps

Some are more like holes and some have nails protruding that actually pricks

I suspect it's just poor workmanship but why did it have to be nailed in the first place?

What is the industry standard?

They said they used the thinnest nails possible but the first two steps doesn't have any so I think they carefully installed 2 steps and then stopped caring

There must be a nail size that can generate grip without piercing through flooring

And I don't think Shaw would be in business to sell this stair nose if every single installation results in issues like this

[image: Workmanship]
[image: Flush nose]

Comment: Will need to read the installation instructions.  For something like that I figure glue/adhesive is recommended over nails.

Comment: Somebody got a new power nailer to use and they went to town with it.

Comment: You have 3 different questions here - please take the [tour] so you can see how this place works. Please [edit] this down to what you're really after, as it's confusing me. Are you asking about how to install the flooring, about the quality of the workmanship or what some sort of "industry standard" is?

Answer (score 3):

Bottom line LVP flooring and the accessories that go with them should not be nailed.

Because of the material make-up of LVP, nails will fracture the core damaging the product.

If it needs to be anchored to a surface it should be glued.

The type of glue depends on the flooring manufacturer recommendations for the surface you will be gluing to.

The worker that nailed those should be called back and tasked with replacement of each piece that had a nail shot in it.

Comment: TBH, I'd demand that the worker/his company pay someone else who is actually _competent_ to do the replacement. This is the epitome of shoddy workmanship!

Comment: Thank you for the answer
I have scheduled for someone to come inspect it but I wanted to know in advance so I don't get swindled.
They should cover this with their warranty by redoing pretty much every single step and every single piece minus 2, but still a major inconvenience especially recommendations like "let the adhesives set by not using the stairs for 24h" is impossible to adhere to

Comment: @Depi - it's *possible* but requires you get the odd steps done one day & the even steps the next. Then you carefully only walk on the ones that have had time to set.